How can I get TS type for an instance of dynamically imported class constructor?
I am using dynamic import to import and instantiate a class from jsondiffpatch library:
async function someFunction() {
  const jsondiffpatch = await import('jsondiffpatch')
  const DiffPatcherInstance = new jsondiffpatch.DiffPatcher()
}

How can I capture DiffPatcher instance type as a module-level exportable entity?

I found out I can do this:
type Foo = typeof import('jsondiffpatch')["DiffPatcher"]

but unfortunately does not work, DiffPatcher instance (new DiffPatcher()) is not assignable to Foo.
If I understand this correctly, Foo seems to resolve to typeof DiffPatcher instead of DiffPatcher - it describes the class itself, not an instance.
I can also use typeof on my instance, but only inside the someFunction scope - I don't think it is possible to smuggle it outside to the module scope and export it.
How can this be solved?

Are you just looking for the InstanceType<T> utility type as shown in this playground link? If so I can write an answer (or find a suitable duplicate source). If not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Oh wow - yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. Silly I've missed this. Thank you very much!
